# Get Precise xpath from general xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to do 2 thing.

1. Verify a value of a node in a XML file.
2. If the value correspond, I need to change it.

   I already have a complex hierarchy of object that do this job. Now I'm facing a problematic case. Lets look at an example:

   ```
   <staticTag>
     <randomTag>
       <anotherRandomTag>  
         <staticTag property="id">
            <staticTag> VALUE </staticTag>
         </staticTag>  
       </anotherRandomTag>  
     </randomTag>  
   </staticTag>
   ```

This happen n time in each XMLFile I have to parse. It would be easy with

```
//staticTag[@property='id']/staticTag/text()
```

Yes it will return to me all the value i need to verify. The problem is I don't have the precise xpath to change the value if it correspond to the value I am looking for.

I may post sample of code if necessary. So tl;dr : Is there a way to generate precise xpath from a general one? As usual thank you for your time.

I have done a few more testHere is a dummy xml

```
<tag>
   <ZDSJG>
      <SJROT>X66P1</SJROT>
   </ZDSJG>
   <DNLVZ>
      <SJROT>VV1EZ</SJROT>
   </DNLVZ>
</tag>
```

My Xpath xpression that I am looking for is `//SJROT`
With a function i wrote I can generate this XPATH from the first node : `/#document/tag/ZDSJG/SJROT/#text`

Unfortunately the xpath expression `//SJROT` don't return me the second node that have this name.
Here a snippet of code that look for the Xpath expression provided

```
    XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(expressionXPath);

    NodeList result = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);

    List<String> generatedXpath = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.getLength(); i++) {
        generatedXpath.add(getXPath(result.item(i)));
    }
    return generatedXpath;
```

Another edit: I fixed my code, I had to use `NODESET` instead of `NODE`
Will no try to generate the proper Xpath

Comment: Why not use `"staticTag[@property='id']"` , without the leading `/`? -- your topmost tag will not match because it does not have that attribute.

Comment: I have this pattern N time. In the same XML File. And i don't need to change all those N instance. Just if the value match another one in memory.

Comment: I guess you need to catch the middle `<staticTag>` with the attribute (I suppose there are no other nodes with `property="id"` attribute) -- can you do that? We have no information of your XML.

Comment: I have updated the question with another example and some snippet of code. I hope what I am trying to achieve look more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not found anything that would generate me the XPath from a node. I did my own. It is pretty basic and could be improve in so many ways. But at the moment it fit my needs. If anybody have a better solution I will gladly accept it. Here is my java code: feel free to improve it

```
    public List<String> generateAbsoluteXpath(File fileToRead, String expressionXPath) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document document = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(fileToRead);

    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(expressionXPath);
    NodeList result = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    List<String> generatedXpath = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.getLength(); i++) {
        generatedXpath.add(getXPath(result.item(i)));
    }
    return generatedXpath;
}



public String getXPath(Node node)
{
    Node parent = node.getParentNode();
    if (parent == null || parent.getNodeName().equals("#document")) {
        return "/" + node.getNodeName();
    }
    return getXPath(parent) + "/" + node.getNodeName();
}
```

So Basically, I input an XPath that will generate multiple node. It return me the list of absolute xpath referencing the node that were found with the general path. Since i have the absolute xpath the other object I am working with may now read / replace the value. Problem solved.